# Share Post With Image Text And url To facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, sharekit

I am using share kit in my app and trying to post to facebook pose that include small photo, when clicked on facebook it will be opened to larger size like any other photo.

Link to the app on the app store and text about this post.

I am using this code:

```
    SHKItem *item;
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8"];
item = [SHKItem URL:url title:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I'm playing someGame on my iPhone! My Highscore is %i, think you can beat it?", 1400]];    
[SHKFacebook shareItem:item];
```

What do I need to change to add photo to this post?

Answer (score 2):

For ShareKit  See: http://www.getsharekit.com/docs/#image

Comment: I know that is not related to the content of the question, but I'll try. What is the conf on Facebook to use sharekit? I don't have a the moment an iPhone app store id.... so